# How to use log4j 2.1.0 over slf4j 1.7.7 in Eclipse RCP? Getting "ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation."

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, slf4j, log4j2

I'm trying to get the above setup working.

Here's what I've done.

1. Built a p2 repo including `slf4j.api_1.7.7.jar`, `org.apache.logging.log4j.core_2.1.0.jar`, `org.apache.logging.log4j.api_2.1.0.jar`, `org.apache.logging.log4j.slf4j-impl_2.1.0.jar`.
2. Consumed this p2 repo in my target platform + added it to the parent POM.
3. Added all 4 plugins to my Eclipse plugin project as dependencies in MANIFEST.MF.
4. Created a file `log4j2.xml` in the `src/main/resources` folder in my Eclipse plugin. Content below.
5. Added a `private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class)` field to `MyClass`
6. In `MyClass` called `logger.info("Hi from logger")`.

Running the whole affair, I'm getting an error message: `ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...`

So it seems that `log4j` is up and running? and that `slf4j` can "use" `log4j`? Right?

The `.classpath` is shown below the `log4j2.xml`.

What, then, is the problem?

log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
 </Configuration>
```

.classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes/"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use [Buddy Class Loading](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Context_Class_Loader_Enhancements#Buddy_Class_Loading).

I had encapsulated log4j and slf4j etc. in an extra plugin which I wanted to make consumable by other plugins. It worked when I registered a *BuddyPolicy* in the logging plugin's `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered
```

I also had to register the logging plugin (here: `my.app.logging`) as a *Buddy* (again, in `MANIFEST.MF`) in the plugin that I wanted to be able to "consume" the logging plugin (i.e. the core plugin - the one containing my IApplication class):

```
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: my.app.logging
```

This way, to put it very simple, the plugins "share" a class loader, cf. the Buddy Class Loading link above.